# Alamofire Asynchronous requests happening out of order in for loop

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, httprequest, alamofire

I'm having this strange issue with Alamofire asynchronous requests in Swift. Here is the pseudocode for what I am trying to do.

```
  for each email:
      GET request to grab first_name for email
      add first_name to an array
```

The issue is that the end array is out of order. When it should be [User 3, User 1, User 2] it is instead [User 3, User 2, User 1]. I've tested my backend funtions with Postman and everything works so am confused as to what exactly is the problem. Any insight into what might be happening or why I am not getting the correct result.

Comment: Asynchronous calls are by definition not ordered because any call can finish before any other one - therefore the results are always "out of order", and this is normal.

Comment: Things aren't guaranteed to finish in the order they were asked for with asynchronous computing. If you need to ensure order you should do that after you receive the data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Custom Response Serializer is returning images at random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575392/swift-custom-response-serializer-is-returning-images-at-random)

Comment: look into completion handlers

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous calls are just that. **Asynchronous.**

You cannot guarantee which one will finish first regardless of the order in which they were started.